# List of constraint violations:[...]javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am working on one of the Springboot Application where I am getting error called `List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='*Please provide Template', propertyPath=templateId, rootBeanClass=class com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign, messageTemplate='*Please provide Template'} ]] with root cause javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='*Please provide Template', propertyPath=templateId, rootBeanClass=class com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign, messageTemplate='*Please provide Template'} ]`

This error I am getting When I am trying to Save the data by hitting on the save button, Below is thepicture of the interface:

[image]

The code blocks here I am using are as below:

**SMSCampaign.java**

```
package com.airkomm.model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sms_campaign")
public class SmsCampaign {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "smscampaignId")
    private int smscampaignId;
    
    @Column(name = "campaignName")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide Campaign Name")
    private String campaignName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "smsCampaign", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotEmpty
    private List<SmsCampaignTask> smsCampaignTask = new ArrayList<SmsCampaignTask>();;
    
    @Column(name = "smsText")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide Sms Text")
    private String smsText;
    
    @Column(name = "isTextCustomization")
    private int isTextCustomization;
    
    @Column(name = "scheduleDate")
    private Timestamp scheduleDate;
    
    @Column(name = "scheduleEndDate")
    private Timestamp scheduleEndDate;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
    
    @Column(name = "createdByUserId")
    private int createdByUserId;
    
    @Column(name = "modifiedByUserId")
    private int modifiedByUserId;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "createdDateTime")
    private Timestamp createdDateTime;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updatedDateTime")
    private Timestamp updatedDateTime;
    
    public Timestamp getScheduleEndDate() {
        return scheduleEndDate;
    }

    public void setScheduleEndDate(Timestamp scheduleEndDate) {
        this.scheduleEndDate = scheduleEndDate;
    }

    public int getSmscampaignId() {
        return smscampaignId;
    }

    public void setSmscampaignId(int smscampaignId) {
        this.smscampaignId = smscampaignId;
    }

    public String getCampaignName() {
        return campaignName;
    }

    public void setCampaignName(String campaignName) {
        this.campaignName = campaignName;
    }
    
    public Timestamp getScheduleDate() {
        return scheduleDate;
    }

    public void setScheduleDate(Timestamp scheduleDate) {
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getCreatedByUserId() {
        return createdByUserId;
    }

    public void setCreatedByUserId(int createdByUserId) {
        this.createdByUserId = createdByUserId;
    }

    public int getModifiedByUserId() {
        return modifiedByUserId;
    }

    public void setModifiedByUserId(int modifiedByUserId) {
        this.modifiedByUserId = modifiedByUserId;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDateTime() {
        return createdDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedDateTime(Timestamp createdDateTime) {
        this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
    }

    public Timestamp getUpdatedDateTime() {
        return updatedDateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDateTime(Timestamp updatedDateTime) {
        this.updatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    public List<SmsCampaignTask> getSmsCampaignTask() {
        return smsCampaignTask;
    }

    public int getIsTextCustomization() {
        return isTextCustomization;
    }

    public void setIsTextCustomization(int isTextCustomization) {
        this.isTextCustomization = isTextCustomization;
    }

    public String getSmsText() {
        return smsText;
    }

    public void setSmsText(String smsText) {
        this.smsText = smsText;
    }

    public void setSmsCampaignTask(List<SmsCampaignTask> smsCampaignTask) {
        this.smsCampaignTask = smsCampaignTask;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "entityId")
    @NotNull(message = "*Please provide Entity")
    private int etityId;
    

    @Column(name = "templateId")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide Template")
    private String templateId;
    
    public int getEtityId() {
        return etityId;
    }

    public void setEtityId(int etityId) {
        this.etityId = etityId;
    }

    public String getTemplateId() {
        return templateId;
    }

    public void setTemplateId(String templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }
    
}
```

**SMSCampaignController.java**

```
package com.airkomm.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.airkomm.dao.CliDao;
import com.airkomm.dao.EntitysDao;
import com.airkomm.dao.PrivilegesDao;
import com.airkomm.dao.SmsCampaignDao;
import com.airkomm.dao.TemplatsDao;
import com.airkomm.form.SmsCampaignForm;
import com.airkomm.form.SmsCampaignFormMapping;
import com.airkomm.main.Const;
import com.airkomm.model.Pack;
import com.airkomm.model.PackageChannelMapping;
import com.airkomm.model.Privileges;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaignTask;
import com.airkomm.model.User;
import com.airkomm.service.PackageService;
import com.airkomm.service.SmsCampaignService;
import com.airkomm.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class SMSCampaignController {

    private static final Logger _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SMSCampaignController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SmsCampaignService smsCampaignService;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegesDao privilegesDao;

    @Autowired
    private SmsCampaignDao smsCampaignDao;

    @Autowired
    private PackageService packageService;


    @Autowired
    CliDao cliDao;

    @Autowired
    EntitysDao entitysDao;
    
    @Autowired
    TemplatsDao templatsDao;
    
    @Value("${smsfileupload.path}")
    private String smsfileuploadPath;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/SMSCampaign" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSMSCampaignList() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        List<Privileges> privilegesShownList = privilegesDao.getPrivilegesListByUser(user.getUserId());
        modelAndView.addObject("leftMenuList", privilegesShownList.isEmpty() ? null : privilegesShownList);
//        List<SmsCampaign> smsCampaignList = smsCampaignService.findSmsCampaignCreatedByUserId(user.getUserId());
        List<SmsCampaign> smsCampaignList = smsCampaignDao.getSmsCampaignByUserId(user.getUserId(), null, null);
        List<SmsCampaignForm> smsCampaignFormList = smsCampaignList.stream()
                .map(obj -> SmsCampaignFormMapping.mapToForm(obj, user.getUsername())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        modelAndView.addObject("smsCampaignList", smsCampaignFormList.isEmpty() ? null : smsCampaignFormList);
        modelAndView.addObject("smsCampaignForm", new SmsCampaignForm());
        modelAndView.addObject("cliOptions", cliDao.getAvailableCliForUser(user.getUserId()));
        modelAndView.addObject("entityOptions", entitysDao.getAvailabeEntitysForUser(user.getUserId()));
        modelAndView.addObject("templateOptions", templatsDao.getAvailabeTemplateForUser(user.getUserId()));
        modelAndView.setViewName("smscampaign");
        _logger.info("campignManagement Controller ends");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/createSmsCampaign" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> createSmsCampaign(@Valid SmsCampaignForm smsCampaignForm, BindingResult result)
            throws ParseException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        List<String> textSMSWithShortUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
        if ((smsCampaignForm.getUrlShortner() != null) && (smsCampaignForm.getUrlShortner() == true)) {
            List<String> shortUrlList = smsCampaignForm.getFilePathForURL();
            for(String shortURL:shortUrlList) {
            String smstexturl=smsCampaignForm.getSmsText().replace(smsCampaignForm.getSmsUrlFind(), shortURL);
            textSMSWithShortUrl.add(smstexturl);
            }
            
        } else {
            String smstexturl=smsCampaignForm.getSmsText();
            textSMSWithShortUrl.add(smstexturl);
        }
        
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(auth.getName());

        Pack pack = packageService.findPackageByPackageId(user.getPackageId());
        PackageChannelMapping smsPackgChannelMapping = pack.getPackageChannelMappings().stream()
                .filter(packgChannel -> packgChannel.getChannelType() == Const.CAMPAIGN_CHANNEL_TYPE_SMS).findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        SmsCampaign smsCampaign = SmsCampaignFormMapping.mapToModel(smsCampaignForm);
        smsCampaign.setCreatedByUserId(user.getUserId());
        smsCampaign.setCreatedDateTime(new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
        smsCampaign.setUpdatedDateTime(new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
        
        smsCampaign = smsCampaignService.saveCampaign(smsCampaign);
        int totalCount = 0;
        if (smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderFile() != null) {
            
            totalCount = smsCampaignService.saveMt(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderFile(),
                    smsCampaign.getSmsCampaignTask().get(0).getTaskId(), smsPackgChannelMapping.getTotalQuota(),
                    smsPackgChannelMapping.getUsedQuota(), smsCampaign.getIsTextCustomization(),
                    smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getModeId(),
                    textSMSWithShortUrl, smsCampaignForm.getUrlcampId());
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderAddress())) {
            smsCampaignService.saveMt(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderAddress(),
                    smsCampaign.getSmsCampaignTask().get(0).getTaskId());
            totalCount++;
        }
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("totalCount", String.valueOf(totalCount));
        System.out.println("Create Campaign Controller");
//      System.out.println(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderFile());
//      System.out.println(smsCampaignForm.getSmsText());
//      System.out.println(smsCampaignForm.getCampaignName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/createSmsTask" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> createSmsTask(@Valid SmsCampaignForm smsCampaignForm, BindingResult result)
            throws ParseException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        List<String> textSMSWithShortUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(textSMSWithShortUrl);
        SmsCampaignTask smsCampaignTask = SmsCampaignFormMapping
                .mapToTaskModel(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm());
        Optional<SmsCampaign> smsCampaign = smsCampaignService.findSmsCampaignById(smsCampaignForm.getSmscampaignId());
        System.out.println(smsCampaign);
        Pack pack = packageService.findPackageByPackageId(user.getPackageId());
        PackageChannelMapping smsPackgChannelMapping = pack.getPackageChannelMappings().stream()
                .filter(packgChannel -> packgChannel.getChannelType() == Const.CAMPAIGN_CHANNEL_TYPE_SMS).findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        int totalCount = 0;
        if (smsCampaign.isPresent()) {
            smsCampaignTask.setSmsCampaign(smsCampaign.get());
            smsCampaignService.saveCampaignTask(smsCampaignTask);
            if (smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderFile() != null) {
                
                 String smstextwithurl=smsCampaign.get().getSmsText();
                 int urlCampId = 0;
                 textSMSWithShortUrl.add(smstextwithurl);
                System.out.println(textSMSWithShortUrl);
                totalCount = smsCampaignService.saveMt(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderFile(),
                        smsCampaignTask.getTaskId(), smsPackgChannelMapping.getTotalQuota(),
                        smsPackgChannelMapping.getUsedQuota(), smsCampaign.get().getIsTextCustomization(),
                        smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getModeId(),
                        textSMSWithShortUrl, urlCampId);
                System.out.println(totalCount);
            }
            if (smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderAddress() != null) {
                smsCampaignService.saveMt(smsCampaignForm.getSmsCampaignTaskForm().getSenderAddress(),
                        smsCampaignTask.getTaskId());
                totalCount++;
            }
        }
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("totalCount", String.valueOf(totalCount));
        System.out.println("Create Task Controller");
        System.out.println(response);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

**SMSCampaignService.java**

```
package com.airkomm.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.airkomm.dao.DndDao;
import com.airkomm.form.SmsCampaignForm;                                        
import com.airkomm.main.Const;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaign;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsCampaignTask;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsCustomizationData;
import com.airkomm.model.SmsMt;
import com.airkomm.repository.SmsCampaignRepository;
import com.airkomm.repository.SmsCampaignTaskRepository;
import com.airkomm.repository.SmsMtRepository;

@Service("smsCampaignService")
public class SmsCampaignService {

private SmsCampaignRepository smsCampaignRepository;
    
    private SmsCampaignTaskRepository smsCampaignTaskRepository;
    
    private SmsMtRepository smsMtRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    DndDao dndDao;

    @Autowired
    public SmsCampaignService(SmsCampaignRepository smsCampaignRepository, 
            SmsCampaignTaskRepository smsCampaignTaskRepository, SmsMtRepository smsMtRepository) {
        this.smsCampaignRepository = smsCampaignRepository;
        this.smsCampaignTaskRepository = smsCampaignTaskRepository;
        this.smsMtRepository = smsMtRepository;
    }

    public Optional<SmsCampaign> findSmsCampaignById(Integer smscampaignId) {
        return smsCampaignRepository.findById(smscampaignId);
    }
    
    public List<SmsCampaign> findSmsCampaignCreatedByUserId(Integer createdByUserId) {
        return smsCampaignRepository.findAllByCreatedByUserId(createdByUserId);
    }
    
    public void updateSmsCampaign(SmsCampaign smsCampaign) {
        smsCampaignRepository.save(smsCampaign);
    }
    
    public void deleteSmsCampaign(SmsCampaign smsCampaign) {
        smsCampaignRepository.delete(smsCampaign);
    }
    
    public SmsCampaign saveCampaign(SmsCampaign smsCampaign) {
        return smsCampaignRepository.save(smsCampaign);
    }
    
    public void saveCampaignTask(SmsCampaignTask smsCampaignTask) {
        smsCampaignTaskRepository.save(smsCampaignTask);
    }
    
   
}
```

**SmsCampaignRepo**

```
@Repository("smsCampaignTaskRepository")
public interface SmsCampaignTaskRepository extends JpaRepository<SmsCampaignTask, Integer> {

}
```

Also, The table **SMS_Campaign** is:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| smscampaignId       | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| campaignName        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| smsText             | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| scheduleDate        | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| scheduleEndDate     | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| status              | tinyint      | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| createdByUserId     | int          | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| modifiedByUserId    | int          | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| customizationText   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| isTextCustomization | tinyint      | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| createdDateTime     | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| updatedDateTime     | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Please note, this DB is existing DB, I have made changes in my project to implement the new feature, But I have also given the Proper annotations so in that case the columns like entityId, templateId must be added, that is also not happening.

Please help it would be appreciated.

I have tried changing the @NotNull to id value i.e. `@Column(name = "entityId") @NotNull(message = "*Please provide Entity") private int etityId;`
 **&** 
   `@Column(name = "templateId") @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide Template") private String templateId;`

Comment: Please post only the necessary part of the code, if you want answers early or if at all. There are commented code, unrelated controller methods, etc. You will appreciate that it will help a lot without all this. The question is actually interesting but leads to a lot of time loss in analysis. Hope you appreciate the point.

Comment: @SreeKumar, Thanks Sree, Have removed the Commented codes! Please check now if possible.

Comment: you need to know how to write question, people not coming here to read a book, they want to see the problem quick. let me help you with this: you encountered an error, the error give you a clue which is expception and field/column name. so, you can include the pojo but not all of it, also, if there constraint violation, you may add the table definition (creation) but again you don't need to provide all, just the part related to the problem. Also, show the method where you save, but focus on the part that you set the value that realated the problem.